# Image avergaing and keeping the images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, average, processing-efficiency

I am recording a number of images and store them in a 3-dimensional array like a "stacked pile" of images, like this:

```
 for i = 1:numberOfImages
    ima = pfREAD_IMAGE(board_handle, 0, imasize, ima_ptr, 30000);
    imArray(:,:,i) = ima;
 end
```

Where `pfREAD_IMAGE()` is the function to acquire the images. Afterwards I want to calculate the average of all images, but keep all the individual images. I do it like this:

```
[imHeight, imWidth, imStackHeight] = size(imArray);
avgIma = zeros(imHeight, imWidth);
for i = 1:imHeight
    for j = 1:imWidth
        avgIma(i,j) = mean(imArray(i,j,:));
    end
end
```

This method works, but is very slow due to MATLAB's slow looping. What is the best way to speed up the averaging?

Comment: `avgIma=mean(imArray,3)`

Comment: @BillBokeey Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [`mean`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) function in MATLAB supports a parameter to set the dimension it is working on.
Since you stacking the images on the 3rd dimension what you should do is apply the Mean Operator on that dimension - `avgIma = mean(imArray, 3)`.